# CSS nav menu-- li a hover state be 100% of parent UL height

Tags: css, navigation, hover, html-lists, nav

I have an otherwise-typical CSS nav menu on a site that uses a language translation plugin. Some translations end up longer than others, which results in a problem where some li items are two lines long, while the sibling li's are still just one line long. The parent UL stretches vertically to accommodate the longer items, but because the shorter sibling li's are just one line long, they do not style quite right.

This is hard to explain with words. see screenshot:
[css screenshot http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6448156/CAP-hover.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6448156/CAP-hover.png)

As you can see, the two-liners are fine, but the sibling one-liners need to take on the height of the parent UL so that the white border on the right goes all the way down, and the hover state also goes all the way down.

How do I style these li items so that they fill 100% of the parent UL height? (because setting height to 100% just sets it to 100% of itself)

You can see a live sample at http://cap.wizzywighost.com/?s=post&lang=fr

Would love a hand with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution should be to set border-right: 1px solid #fff to be a property of the li and not the child a.

right now your code should look something like this:

a{...
border-right: 1px solid #fff
...}

You want it to look like this:
li{...
border-right: 1px solid #fff
...}

a{...}

Answer (score 0):

Let's look into [the specs for height calculation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the
>   generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to 'auto'.

Given that you are not setting an explicit value on the parent `<ul>` (because... well, you can't - you don't know the height of the tallest box in advance), it would ignore `height:100%;` on menu items.

Rendering that block of navigation as a table would not be affected by the above. Given that you'd probably want to vertically-align nav items in the menu too, there's no shame in using a table here, especially given its widest support range as opposed to, say, using `display:table*;` styles.

### Update:

I saw your comment on not being able to use tables. If you are happy to give up vertical alignment, [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) would be an easy trick to implement. What this does is it increases the rendered height of a menu item with padding, but offsets any layout space taken with negative margin:

```
.menu-item, .menu-item a {
    padding-bottom:999px !important;margin-bottom:-999px !important;
}
```

You don't actually have to use `!important` as long as these properties are added to the correct rules, [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/4kShs/3/). IMO this is the easiest height-agnostic fix you could use.

Comment: Yeah that was all I could come up with too, but felt that was a bad way to do it. But I might have to if this is the only solution. It's a wordpress site though, and the UL is automatically generated. I would have to see if there is any way to change that so it outputs a table instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it two solutions for your navigation first one is i just defined the **min-height:50px:** to your class **div.nav ul li a**

as mentioning below the updated **CSS**

```
div.nav ul li a {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 5px 10px 3px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 167px;
}
```

once you will update your css with this class you will get it the desired result i think you are looking this.....

**Second Method**

I have played with padding without use of **Width and Height** so you can see the alternate method also... check the second method **CSS**

```
div.nav {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #89BFE4;
    clear: both;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 199;
}
div.nav ul {
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
div.nav ul li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9900;
}
div.nav ul li {
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
div.nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div.nav ul li:last-child a {
    border-right: medium none;
}
div.nav ul li a:hover, div.nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: white;
}
.current-menu-item {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9900;
}
div.nav ul ul {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FF9900;
    display: none;
    left: 93px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 42px;
    width: 250px;
    z-index: 200;
}
div.nav ul ul li {
    clear: left;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
div.nav ul ul li:hover, div.nav ul ul li:hover a {
    color: #FF9900;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
}
div.nav ul ul li a, div.nav ul li.active li a {
    color: white;
    width: 250px;
}
div.nav ul ul li a:hover, div.nav ul li.active ul li a:hover, div.nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover, div.nav ul li.hover ul li a:hover {
}
div.nav ul > li:hover > ul, div.nav ul > li.hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

I hope this can be also helpful for you i tried to gave you the nearest solution of your question....

Comment: No, this solution is not accurate for our situation. The design requires that each menu item is a specified width, which is why we can't let them stretch horizontally as needed. (that is what your solution does).

In addition, the top solution also does not work because the li's cannot be explicitly sized. This is the whole problem. Otherwise I would have made them 50px tall. But then it looks bad when viewing in english etc.